# Trouble with offset().top with floating divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor-scroll

I have a page with sticky navigation for sections within that page. Sticky nav and inline anchors work fine, but if I go directly to the page and checking for `window.location.hash`, I'm running into a problem, the `offset().top` is not calculated properly. This is because one of my section has a series of floating divs (to form a grid) and the calculation is viewing the divs height (stacked) before the float happens. One way around it.. and I hate this option is to wait 2 seconds then perform the `scrollTo()`.

Is there way to make this calculation immediately after the floats execute? I've tried `$(window).load()` and behavior is intermittent. I also feel that my `setTimeout()` will be incorrect depending on load speeds, etc.

Or is there a way to scrollTo without calculating offset and just go directly to the `div#id`?

This is how I'm managing it right now:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var ID = '#' + window.location.hash.substr(1);
        $.scrollTo($(ID).offset().top- nav_height2, 800, {axis:'y'}) ;
     }, 2000);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make a quick Plunker (plnkr.co) or JSFiddle to show everything. Seeing your css and/or other JS may help
(not enough reputation to comment yet sorry)

Comment: I think that would be hard to do with the amount of content required to cause the lag.. which causes the problem in the first place.